# How can we automate the incremental import in Sqoop from DB to HBase using linux script

Tags: shell, hadoop, hbase, sqoop, sqoop2

Using sqoop job we can do the incremental load to HBase using the `--lastval`

But how we can do the same with shell script and how we will get the `--lastval` when we automate the script ?

I mean how to store the `--lastval` and how to pass it to the next time

Thankyou in Advance for the help !!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> how to store the --lastval and how to pass it to the next time?

define `--lastval` as an alias or export variable in linux or unix. which can be retried from automation script

[once load is finish then  change it to recent value, by capturing latest lastva](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34771407/how-can-we-automate-incremental-import-in-sqoop?rq=1)l

`export lastupdatedvalue=hive -e 'select last_value from table` #selection query based on the logic.

```
sqoop import --connect jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/ydb --table <your table> --username root -P --incremental append --last-value ${lastupdatedvalue}
```

:

> You can try a sqoop action in Oozie, it should work. Else use shell action in
>   oozie if you prefer scripts. It is possible to schedule it using
>   coordinator function available.

Also have a look at

#### Importing data incrementally

[To import data in increments, you use the --incremental argument with the import command. Sqoop compares the values in a check column against a reference value for the most recent import. These arguments import all rows having an id greater than 100.](https://docs.datastax.com/en/datastax_enterprise/4.5/datastax_enterprise/ana/anaSqpJob.html)

```
--incremental
--check-column id
--last-value 100
```

If you run an incremental import from the command line, Sqoop prints the last value in a subsequent incremental import. If you run an incremental import from a saved job, Sqoop retains the last value in the saved job. To import only newer rows than those previously imported, use the --exec  option. Sqoop imports only rows having an id greater than the specified row id.

Comment: Thankyou RamPrasad, if you dont mind can i have a code snippet.